# C# different mail body on condition

Tags: c#, forms, email, radio-button

I have a form with two radio buttons and depending on which form is checked a different process will run. I want to send an e-mail notification when either process completes but have the subject and body indicate which process is complete.

```
class SendMail
{
    public void sendMail()
    {
        MailMessage dailyMail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com");
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
        dailyMail.Subject = "Daily load done";
        dailyMail.Body = "The daily load process has completed.";
        client.Send(dailyMail);
    }
}
```

Just using this generic sendMail method, should I keep the dailyMail object (for one process) and create a monthlyMail object (for the other process) and have the corresponding object trigger with the proper radio button selected?

Is there a better(read: simpler) way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the dailyMail object to the method

```
class SendMail
{
    public void sendMail(MailMessage dailyMail)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
        client.Send(dailyMail);
    }
}
```

You can then create the dailyMail object and set the subject and body before calling the method e.g.

```
var dailyMail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com");
if(radioButton1.Checked)
{
    dailyMail.Subject = "Daily load done";
    dailyMail.Body = "The daily load process has completed.";
}
else
{
    dailyMail.Subject = "Some other subject";
    dailyMail.Body = "Some other method";
}
var sendMail = new SendMail();
sendMail.sendMail(dailyMail);
```

Comment: So it seems like I should be able to change the string content of  .Body and .Subject depending on which radio box is checked.

Comment: Yes you could put an if statement around the setting of the subject and the body, I'll edit my answer to show this

Comment: Yep this is the exact simple logic that I simply could not come up with today! I'll chalk up the blame to it being Friday. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad you have a solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code it's a bit hard to determine approach but it might be best to create a base mail class that child classes inherit from. Those child classes set the subject/body/anything else that needs it.

```
public abstract class MailBase
{
    private SmtpClient _client;

    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public MailBase()
    {
         _client = new SmtpClient();
         _client.Port = 25;
         _client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
         _client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
         _client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
    }

    protected void SendInternal()
    {
        //Send code
    }
}

public class DailyMail : MailBase
{
    public DailyMail(string to)
    {
         To = to;
         From = "someemail@email.com";
         Subject = "My Subject";
         Body = "My body";
    }

    public void Send()
    {
         SendInternal();
    }
}
```

You could then just instantiate that type and call `Send`.

```
//Somewhere in code
var dailyMail = new DailyMail("user@email.com");
dailyMail.Send();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to the others, but takes advantage of putting the mail sending in a static method so the call is a little cleaner and resources are properly disposed.  Also, the UI/presentation code can be separated a bit more to make it easier to send other mail messages in the future if more radio buttons ever need to be added (or if you want to reuse the code in other classes or projects).

```
public class Mailer
{
    public static void Send(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Port = 25;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
            client.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

In UI or presentation-layer code:

```
private void HandleRadioSelection()
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        this.SendMailMessage("Daily load done.", "The daily load process has completed.");
    }
    else
    {
        this.SendMailMessage("Some other subject", "Some other body");
    }
}

private void SendMailMessage(string subject, string body)
{
    using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com", subject, body))
    {
        Mailer.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```